# parsing non-strict json, one in which keys are not enclosed in quotes, with Java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am trying to parse a string which in JSON format only that keys are not enclosed in quotes.  I can very well parse this string in Javascript, but can not find a Java API which will help me parse this.  All the APIs I tried assumes strict JSON format.

Can anyone suggest a library which has an option to parse this, or a whole new approach to the problem (say like use regex instead) ?

Comment: http://www.json.org/js.html says "JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript". So I guess my question now becomes, is there a Java parser for object literal notation of Javascript.

Comment: In 2021, it's definitely common to have "relaxed JSON", where keys don't need to be surrounded with quotes, single quotes can be used around values (instead of double-quotes), etc. http://oleg.fi/relaxed-json/ was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys aren't enclosed in quotes then it's not JSON.

You should either hack this yourself or find someone who did it already.

Also, there's no such thing as *non-strict json*. There's only 1 version of JSON and it's strict.

Comment: I am now trying to hack on org.json code to remove this restriction.  Just wanted to see if anyone has a nicer way around this.

Comment: Also, wonder why javascript does not complain about keys not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Because JSON is not JavaScript object notation, even though that's what it stands for.

Comment: @Nishan: you should also wonder why you can have functions as values in JavaScript... Anyway you could pass your object to a browser and use JSON.stringify on json.org to make the keys have quotes again. You still need a JS interpreter though (the browser).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in coffeescript using the underscore library.  If you're not using that you can replace _.foldl with a for loop.

```
 parseNonStrictJson = (value) ->
        inQuote = false
        correctQuotes = (memo, nextChar) ->
            insertQuote =
                (inQuote and not /[a-z0-9_"]/.test nextChar) or
                (!inQuote and /[a-z_]/.test nextChar)
            inQuote = (inQuote != (insertQuote or nextChar == '"') )
            memo + (if insertQuote then '"' else '') + nextChar
        valueWithQuotes = _.foldl(value + '\n', correctQuotes, "")
        JSON.parse(valueWithQuotes)
```

And the same in javascript:

```
function parseNonStrictJson(value) {
  var correctQuotes, inQuote, valueWithQuotes;
  inQuote = false;
  correctQuotes = function(memo, nextChar) {
    var insertQuote;
    insertQuote = (inQuote && !/[a-z0-9_"]/.test(nextChar)) || (!inQuote && /[a-z_]/.test(nextChar));
    inQuote = inQuote !== (insertQuote || nextChar === '"');
    return memo + (insertQuote ? '"' : '') + nextChar;
  };
  valueWithQuotes = _.foldl(value + '\n', correctQuotes, "");
  return JSON.parse(valueWithQuotes);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, you could use a state pattern and add your quotes.  Unless I am wrong, the state pattern would read in character by character and set flags to indicate whether we are within a double quote condition and whether our double quotes are "quoted" with a backslash.  Using this, and that variable names don't start with a number, you could add the quotes while streaming it, then send it on it's way.

Comment: This is pretty much what json.org's implementation does. I was able to solve this by extending org.json.JSONTokener class.

Answer (score 0):

You might use eval:

```
var parsed = eval(json)
```

Be careful because `eval` could also run code so you must be sure that you know what you are parsing.
There is also a node module called [jsonic](https://github.com/rjrodger/jsonic) that parses non stirct JSON.