# Play Framework json labels without quotes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

Is there any way to make play framework accept json labels without quotes?

I mean:

Accept not just:

{ "key" : "value" }

also:

{ key : "value" }

Thanks!

Comment: Although it specifies java, the answer to the question for scala is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993848/parsing-non-strict-json-one-in-which-keys-are-not-enclosed-in-quotes-with-java

Answer (score 1):

No, because that does not follow the [json](http://json.org/) specification.

You could theoretically use the Nashorn scripting engine (available in the JVM) to parse the javascript object literal notation.